# Detect if if the user switched to another app than Chrome with the Chrome extension API

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, window

I am building a time tracker chrome extension. I need to know if a user has exited chrome and is using another application.

Is any specific chrome extension fired if a user switches to another application?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using this API

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged

If windowId is -1 the focus is out of the application.